# Can SSIS packages access the network when launched from DTExec?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dtexec

I have an SSIS package that pulls some data out of SQL Server into a .csv file, then copies the file to a network location (uses Robocopy). Runs fine as a SQL Agent job. When I use DtExec from my own machine, Robocopy fails with 'Access is denied.'
The same error occurs regardless of which network location I enter. If I use Robocopy to try to copy to a local drive on the server instead, it works fine. DtExec is running as my own account. If I use remote desktop to login to the server (again with my own account) I can access all the network shares, and run Robocopy directly no problem. I am using UNC names throughout - no drive letters anywhere.

Is it possible DtExec is running under some low-privilege account on the server that cannot access any network resources? If so, any ideas on how to work around it?

Comment: Have you tried using the File System Task in SSIS to move files?

Comment: @JasonB. no, might be a good test, but won't work in practice - we started with the basic File System task, but had to move to Robocopy as we are moving very large files over unreliable WAN. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to access these network locations directly (without RDP)? Just paste the network location to the address bar of any windows explorer window. Share permissions of a folder might be different then actual file system permissions so files might be accessible through RDP but unavailable through network SMB.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor - yes I can access the network locations directly, no problem. Much appreciated, though

Comment: Can you verify the credentials that DTEXEC and Perfmon are using?  One way to do this is using PerfMon. See http://improve.dk/solving-access-denied-errors-using-process-monitor/